# Excel Freezes on Laptop Monitor but not on second display

Tags: microsoft-excel, laptop, multiple-monitors, freeze, microsoft-excel-2016

I generally have my laptop hooked up to an external monitor (or two) and spend most of my work day using excel (2016).  I'm on Windows 10.

A week or so ago my organization pushed through several updates to my computer.  Soon afterwards I began to notice every time I had an excel window open on my laptop screen (as opposed to an external monitor) the area with the scroll bar at the bottom would continuously move back and forth, like it would if I grabbed hold of the resizing area of the scroll bar and moved it left and right rapidly.  Then I noticed my excel freezing constantly. I finally realized it almost always froze when an excel screen is up on my laptop screen instead of my external monitor.  Even worse, this continues to happen when I try to use my laptop without an external monitor, making my laptop effectively a desktop for now.  It doesn't always happen instantly, but chances are if I forget and open an excel window on the laptop screen it will freeze within 5 minutes.  I haven't noticed the issue with other office programs.

I have tried disabling graphics acceleration, enabling it again, repairing microsoft office, applying further updates, etc.  Nothing has helped.  Does anybody know what could be causing this or how to fix it?  My IT department was of no assistance.  This is really hampering my productivity.

Comment: This is quite a known issue dating back to 2017. This is related to the screen resolution and scaling used when displaying Worksheets. This was resolved later on by Office and Windows 10 updates. if it doesn't work for you - you need to set 100% scaling and no zoom in Excel to stop crashing.

Comment: Is your computer CPU from Intel? One user suggest disable the "Intel Graphics Control Panel Service" in Services: services.msc. This similar thread is "[Excel 2016 - Freezes when extended to a external Monitor](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/excel-2016-freezes-when-extended-to-a-external/c872460e-a673-46c7-864e-9edffd706c69?page=2)."